# AS3 Saving Filestream to file

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, flash, air

I am trying to import a SQL database into my Adobe Air iOS app.  I have the invoke working and everything seems to work but the new database file can't be read.  Below is my code.

```
function onInvoke(event:InvokeEvent):void{
    if(event.arguments && event.arguments.length)
    {       
        contentUri = event.arguments[0] as String;
        file_db = new File(contentUri);
        fs_db = new FileStream();
        fs_db.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, import_db);
        fs_db.openAsync(file_db, FileMode.READ);    
    }
}
```

My import function looks like this:

```
function import_db(event:Event):void{

    fs_db.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, import_db);
    var fs:FileStream = new FileStream(); 
    var myfile:File=File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath("testDB.db");
    var fileContent:String = fs_db.readUTFBytes(fs_db.bytesAvailable);

    fs.open(myfile,FileMode.WRITE);
    fs.writeUTFBytes(fileContent);
    fs.addEventListener(Event.CLOSE, fileClosed);  
    fs.close();


    function fileClosed(e:Event):void{
    // do other stuff
    }
}
```

Every thing seems to execute but when I try to connect to the database, I get SQL error:

Error #2044: Unhandled SQLErrorEvent:. errorID=3138, operation=open , message=Error #3138: File opened is not a database file.

Any guidance is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, read the bytes into a bytearray and then into the file.

```
var mybytes:ByteArray=new ByteArray();
fs_db.readBytes(mybytes,0,fs_db.bytesAvailable);


fs.openAsync(myfile,FileMode.WRITE);
fs.writeBytes(mybytes,0,mybytes.length);
```